# Can I programmatically call the event for start the reordering cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

Each cell has UITableViewCellReorderControl if canMove return YES value. Possible to create my event and cause, for example via the UILongPressGestureRecognizer to get the cell to start reordering in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout this link :
https://github.com/moayes/UDo/tree/master

1.Add a long press gesture recognizer on the table view.

2.Create a snapshot of the cell when the cell is dragged.

3.As the cell is dragged, move the snapshot around, and call the -`[UITableView moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:].`

4.When the gesture ends, hide the cell snapshot.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @MikhailS Welcome brother :-)